# Parametric Curve Derivative Formula Misunderstanding

Tags: calculus, functions, parametric, parametrization

I was reading [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaTangent.aspx) site 
on determine the derivative and tangents to a parametric curve. However, he begins by saying:

> "suppose that we were able to eliminate the parameter from the parametric form and write the parametric equations in the form $y=F(x$)".

I thought the whole point of parametric equations was that this isn't usually possible (e.g. a circle), and so his argument that follows from there is thus redundant, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the explanation is a little confusing. In my opinion, it's clearer when thinking in terms of linear approximations. Since linear approximations are so fundamental (and often neglected in single variable calculus courses) to understanding more advanced calculus, I will go over them here in case the details are hazy.

Imagine some curvy function, $f(x)$, and pick a point in your mind at $(a, f(a))$. Now imagine a tangent line $T(x)$ at that point. For values of $x$ close to $x=a$, the tangent line is a good approximation for $f(x)$. However, as we go farther away from $x=a$, the tangent line diverges from $f(x)$ and becomes a worse approximation.

Call the change in height (relative to the point we picked above) in the line $\Delta l$. The slope of the tangent line is $\frac{\Delta l}{\Delta x} = f'(a)$, which can be rewritten as $\Delta l = f'(a)\Delta x$. So we can think of $\Delta l$ as a function of $\Delta x$, such that we choose any $\Delta x$ we want, and get a corresponding $\Delta l$.

Now, let $\Delta y$ be the change in the value of $f(x)$, relative to the point we chose earlier. We can say that $\Delta l \approx \Delta y$ for small values of $\Delta x$. To be exact, $\epsilon = \lvert \Delta l - \Delta y\rvert$, where $\epsilon$ is the error. Here is an image to summarize the state of affairs so far:

[image: Linear approximation diagram]

Again, because $\Delta y \approx \Delta l$ for small $\Delta x$, we have that $$\Delta y \approx f'(a)\Delta x$$

(Notice that, when we make $\Delta x$ infinitely small by taking $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}$, we have $dy=f'(a)dx$. We chose $x=a$, but we can in fact choose any $x$ and arrive at $dy=f'(x)dx$, which is the definition of the differential.)

So, to summarize, we now have a function that approximates changes in $f$ near some point $x$, given a change in $x$. That is, $\Delta y \approx f'(x)\Delta x$. It bears repeating that this is a function of $\Delta x$. We choose a fixed value of $x$ (therefore $f'(x)$ is fixed at that point), and let $\Delta x$ vary.

(We can arrive at the chain rule by taking one step further. Assume that $x$ is now a function of $u$. Then, $\Delta x \approx x'(u)\Delta u$, which we can plug into the linearization of $f$ and get $\Delta y \approx f'(x)x'(u)\Delta u$. Dividing both sides by $\Delta u$ and taking $\lim_{\Delta u \to 0}$ gives the single variable chain rule.)

Now, consider a parametric curve $x = x(t)$ and $y = y(t)$. You are entirely right that $y$ is often not a valid function of $x$, since parametric curves can easily fail the vertical line test as many times as they want. Despite this, we can find a slope of the curve. Simply pick an arbitrary point (x, y) on the curve (which has a unique value of $t$ associated with it). Now, we can approximate the slope near this point by computing $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. Making $\Delta t$ smaller makes the slope closer to the slope AT $(x,y)$.

What are $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$? Well, we can use the linear approximations $$\Delta x \approx x'(t)\Delta t$$ $$\Delta y \approx y'(t)\Delta t$$

Then, $$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \approx \frac{y'(t)\Delta t}{x'(t)\Delta t}$$

From here, we can cancel the $\Delta t$s so that $$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \approx \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$$

Then we take $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$ and get $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$$

As we make $\Delta t$ smaller, $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ get smaller as well, until they eventually become $dy$ and $dx$.

Although I prefer that explanation because it gets more to the heart of what $\frac{dy}{dx}$ truly means when $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$, I will try to answer your question more directly.

It is always true that if $y$ is a function of $x$, and $x$ is a function of $t$, then $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$ from the chain rule (provided all the usual conditions are satisfied). You can chop up the parametric curve into a bunch of valid functions of $x$, and put them in a large piecewise function that describes the entire curve. Then, if you're interested in the slope at some point $(x(t_0), y(t_0))$, choose the "piece" on which the point lies, and apply the chain rule to that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this excellent answer - green ticked!

Comment: My other thought was that at a local level, zoomed-in enough so to say, then it is true that we can write y=F(x). Would this be right?

Comment: That's one way of thinking about it, unless you happened to zoom in exactly on a point where $x'(t)=0$ (but even then, perhaps you could zoom infinitely so that the "local curve" becomes a point, at which point it would be a valid function). The important thing here is that you are choosing a particular point on the curve, even though there may be many other points below or above it for the same $x$. So, for some segment of $t$, say $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$, a perfectly normal function of F(x) is traced out (unless $x'(t)=0$ for some $t$ in $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be only a theoretical assumption aimed to derive the given formula for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Once we have that formula, we don't need to eliminate the parameter but we can use directly the formula to find the derivative from the parametric equation.

Comment: But it is extremely rare that one would be able to write y=F(x) as a function, so I don't understand the basis of his assumption

Comment: @Daniele1234 It is indeed a theoretical assumption to obtain the formula, you don't need to write $y=F(x)$ to use that result. The formula is aways valid even if you can't easily obtain $y=F(x)$.

Comment: But then surely, on the page I linked, he is thus only classifying the derivative for parametric equations on a very, very small class of parametric equations, however, he then goes on to use this formula extensively...

Comment: @Daniele1234 Indeed it is not limited, you can use that extensively. From a teoretical point of view if we have a parametric curve such that $\forall t\in(a,b)$ we have that to every $x(t)$ corresponds only and only one value $y(t)$ we can consider the existence of a function $y=F(x)$. We don't need to find explicitely that function it suffices that this function exists.

Comment: I understand this, I am just saying, for example a circle, it is very rare that such a function y=F(x) so doesn't this just make his assumption redundant?

Comment: @Daniele1234 The assumption is only aimed to obtain and justify the general formula. Note that also for a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ we can write for $y>0$ $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. But as already commented, we don't need the expression $y=F(x)$ and we can use directly the parametric equations.

Comment: But how can the assumption obtain and justify the general formula, when the assumption is so so limited in its use..

Comment: @Daniele1234 Note that the given condition $dx/dt \neq 0$ precisely guarantees that such function $y=F(x)$ locally exists.

Comment: he goes on to use the same assumption here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx    and I just can't wrap my head around how he uses this assumption

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write parametric equations in normal Cartesian coordinates. But in some cases its hard.

The reason the person writing the notes says so is because he wants to show how one would find $F'(x)= \frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}$.

His argument  basically says that if $x = f(t), y =g(t)$ and we write the function in terms of $y =F(x)$, we can substiute back $x,y$ to get;

$g(t) = F(f(t))$

differentiating wrt $t$ gives; $g'(t) =F'(f(t))\cdot f'(t) $

$\implies \frac{dy}{dt} =F'(x)\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$

Comment: but in $x^2+y^2=r^2$, one cannot solve that for y and get a function y=F(x)...

Comment: $y = \pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. is it not of the form $y = f(x)$?

Comment: But that is not a function as for one x value there are multiple y values

Comment: you are correct it is not a function. But writing it in the form of $y = f(x)$ does not necessarily imply it should be a function.

Comment: Only that y=f(x) is standard function notation so this seems very confusing (what else could f(x) stand for), and also how do the normal derivative rules apply if it is not a function...

Comment: perhaps i might be wrong. I'll delete that bit from the answer. I think you're correct. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I still don't understand the assumption he is making however, because it is extremely rare that you would be able to write y=F(x) in the first place (a circle being a prime example)...

Comment: It is just an assumption , "suppose that we were able". meaning *if* we could do it.

Comment: But as this assumption is almost always not possible, doesn't that make the rest of his argument redundant for most parametric equations?

Comment: I'd hate to repeat as @gimusi said in his comment .It suffices if one proves that $y=f(x)$ exists but need not find it particularly.

Comment: But that is precisely my point. y=f(x) hardly ever exists for a set of parametric equations, as a simple equation take a circle, and so this derivation of the derivative wouldn't work in many cases (take the circle for example)...

Comment: but it would work in some cases and you can extend it onto other cases